# Find if the file is compressed or not

Tags: shell-script, find, mailx

I need to find whether the file is compressed or not in script.If it is compressed I need to `uncompress` and send as `attachement`. My find command results in two files `sum12.pdf.Z` and `sum23.pdf.Z` My script is

```
dir=/home/as1234/bills
cd $dir
for file in `find . -ctime -1 -type f -name "Sum*pdf*"`
do
if [ ${file: -1} == "Z" ]; then
echo "$file is Zipped"
uncompress $file
uuencode $file
fi
done
uuencode $file $file | mailx -s "subject" abc@gmail.com
```

when I ran this script I got error like

```
 ${file: -1}: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.
```

I am using `ksh`.

Comment: Why don't you use the `file` command to check if it is compressed instead?  For example `file -ib <filename.Z>` will give you the MIME type of the file which you can then use in your tests - `application\x-compress; charset=binary`.  You could then check for that exact string or grep for `compress` maybe? File extensions aren't used in the Unix/Linux world as they are in Windows.

Comment: The `${file:offset}` syntax was introduced in ksh93, you probably have ksh88. Use `case $file in *.Z) ...` (and don't forget to quote your variables!) (and don't use command substitution on the output of find, use `-exec` instead)

Comment: @garethTheRed - in my machine case is not installed. Is there any way to find .Z file?

Comment: From the `man` page for `file`: _There  has been a  file command in every UNIX since at least Research Version 4 (man page dated November, 1973)._ What is your machine?

Answer (score 1):

The filename suffix after the final dot may be had with `${file##*.}`.

In this case though, I would consider doing the uncompressing and the uuencoding with `find -exec` directly like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=/home/as1234/bills

find "$dir" -type f -ctime -1 -name "Sum*.pdf*" -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        filename=$( basename "${pathname%.pdf*}.pdf" )
        if [ "${pathname##*.}" = "Z" ]; then
            uncompress -c "$pathname"
        elif [ "${pathname##*.}" = "gz" ]; then
            gzip -cd "$pathname"
        else
            cat "$pathname"
        fi |
        uuencode "$filename" |
        mailx -s "subject ($filename)" abc@gmail.com
    done' sh {} +
```

This way, you would support pathnames with spaces and other troublesome characters. The `sh -c` script also does not store the uncompressed files but uncompresses them, uuencodes them and sends them in one go.

I also added handling of `gzip`-compressed files.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

---

Alternative implementation of the `sh -c` script using `case ... esac` instead of multiple `if` and `elif` statements.

```
find "$dir" -type f -ctime -1 -name "Sum*.pdf*" -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        filename=$( basename "${pathname%.pdf*}.pdf" )
        case $pathname in
            *.Z)  uncompress -c "$pathname" ;;
            *.gz) gzip -cd "$pathname" ;;
            *)    cat "$pathname"
        esac |
        uuencode "$filename" |
        mailx -s "subject ($filename)" abc@gmail.com
    done' sh {} +
```